# Change row colours for a table

Tags: jquery, html

I would like each each table could look like http://www.maztek.com/blog/using-jquery-to-color-table-rows/. I don't have a lot of experience with html, and I will need your help. Could anyone be able to help me to customize one table in such a way it could look like the table (colors) in the link?

```
{% load i18n %}
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
body, table {
    font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif; 
    font-size: 11px;
}
            h1 {
                margin-bottom: 0;
                padding: 0.3em 0;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #777;
            }
            h2 {
                color: #999;
                font-size: 1.2em;
                padding-top: 0.4em;
            }
            address {
                padding: 0.8em;
                font-size: 0.9em;
            }
            page {
                background: white;
                display: block;
                margin: 0 auto;
                margin-bottom: 0.5cm;
            }
            page[size="A4"] {  
                width: 21cm;
                height: 29.7cm; 
            }
            page[size="A4"][layout="portrait"] {
                width: 29.7cm;
                height: 21cm;  
            }
            page[size="A3"] {
                width: 29.7cm;
                height: 42cm;
            }
            page[size="A3"][layout="portrait"] {
                width: 42cm;
                height: 29.7cm;  
            }
            page[size="A5"] {
                width: 14.8cm;
                height: 21cm;
            }
            page[size="A5"][layout="portrait"] {
                width: 21cm;
                height: 14.8cm;  
            }
            .header,
            .content {
                padding-right: 30%;
            }
            .center {
                text-align: center;
            }
            .border {
                border: 1px solid #777;
            }
            .border td,
            .border th {
                border: 1px solid #777;
            }
            table {
                border-collapse: collapse;
            }
            table td,
            table th {
                border-collapse: collapse;
                padding: 4px 8px;
            }
            @media print {
                body, page {
                    margin: 0;
                }
                .djDebug {
                    display: none;
                }
            }
            @media screen {
                html {
                    background: #999;
                }
                body {
                    margin: 20px 30%;
                    padding-top: 3em;
                    padding-left: 3em;
                }
            }
        </style>
    </head>







    <body>
        <th><center><h1>Test - {% trans "Customer profile" %}</h1><center></th>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
                <tr>
                    <td>{% trans "Date" %}</td>
                    <td>{% now "jS F Y" %}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>{% trans "Customer id" %}</td>
                    <td>{{ customerprofile.amortizing_table_context.customer_code}}</td>
                </tr> 
        </table>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table class="table table-bordered">
                        <tr>
                            <th colspan="2"><h2>{% trans "General informations" %}</h2></th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="field-label col-xs-3 active">
                                <label>{% trans "First name" %}</label>
                            </td>
                            <td class="col-md-9">
                                {{ customerprofile.amortizing_table_context.first_name}}
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>{% trans "Last name" %}</td>
                            <td>{{ customerprofile.amortizing_table_context.last_name}}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>{% trans "Email" %}</td>
                            <td>{{ customerprofile.email}}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>{% trans "Language" %}</td>
                            <td>{{ customerprofile.language }}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>{% trans "Primary phone" %}</td>
                            <td>{{ customerprofile.phone_1 }}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>{% trans "Secondary phone" %}</td>
                            <td>{{ customerprofile.phone_2 }}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>{% trans "Fax" %}</td>
                            <td>{{ customerprofile.fax }}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>{% trans "Social Security number (SSN)" %}</td>
                            <td>{{ customerprofile.ssn }}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>{% trans "Birth date" %}</td>
                            <td>{{ customerprofile.birth_date }}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>{% trans "Principal address" %}</td>
                            <td>{{ customerprofile.address }}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>{% trans "Secondary address" %}</td>
                            <td>{{ customerprofile.address_line2}}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>{% trans "City" %}</td>
                            <td>{{ customerprofile.city }}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>{% trans "State" %}</td>
                            <td>{{ customerprofile.state }}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>{% trans "Zip code" %}</td>
                            <td>{{ customerprofile.zip_code }}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <table class="table table-bordered">
                        <tr>
                            <th colspan="2"> <h2>{% trans "Financial" %}</h2></th>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>{% trans "Income source" %}</td>
                            <td>{{ customerprofile.financialprofile.income_source }}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>{% trans "Bank" %}</td>
                            <td>{{ customerprofile.financialprofile.bank }}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>{% trans "Bank transit" %}</td>
                            <td>{{ customerprofile.financialprofile.bank_transit }}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>{% trans "Bank account" %}</td>
                            <td>{{ customerprofile.financialprofile.bank_account }}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>{% trans "Monthly pay amount" %}</td>
                            <td>{{ customerprofile.financialprofile.pay_amount }}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>{% trans "Pay frequency" %}</td>
                            <td>{{ customerprofile.financialprofile.pay_frequency }}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>{% trans "First pay date" %}</td>
                            <td>{{ customerprofile.financialprofile.first_pay_date }}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>{% trans "Second pay date" %}</td>
                            <td>{{ customerprofile.financialprofile.second_pay_date }}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>{% trans "Monthly micro loan amount" %}</td>
                            <td>{{ customerprofile.financialprofile.micro_loan_monthly_amount }}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>{% trans "Account balance on pay day" %}</td>
                            <td>{{ customerprofile.financialprofile.bank_account_balance_on_pay_day }}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>{% trans "Bankruptcy" %}</td>
                            <td>{% if customerprofile.financialprofile.had_bankruptcy %}
                                {{ "Yes" }}{% else %}{{ "No" }}
                                {% endif %}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>{% trans "Consumer proposal" %}</td>
                            <td>{% if customerprofile.financialprofile.had_consumer_proposal %}
                                {{ "Yes" }}{% else %}{{ "No" }}
                                {% endif %}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table class="table table-bordered">
                        <tr>
                            <th colspan="2"><h2>{% trans "Employer" %}</h2></th>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>{% trans "Company name" %}</td>
                            <td>{{ customerprofile.employerprofile.company_name }}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>{% trans "Job title" %}</td>
                            <td>{{ customerprofile.employerprofile.job_title }}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>{% trans "Date hired" %}</td>
                            <td>{{ customerprofile.employerprofile.date_hired }}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>{% trans "Supervisor name" %}</td>
                            <td>{{ customerprofile.employerprofile.supervisor_name }}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>{% trans "Phone" %}</td>
                            <td>{{ customerprofile.employerprofile.phone }}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>{% trans "Phone extension" %}</td>
                            <td>{{ customerprofile.employerprofile.phone_extension }}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>{% trans "Address" %}</td>
                            <td>{{ customerprofile.employerprofile.address }}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>{% trans "Secondary address" %}</td>
                            <td>{{ customerprofile.employerprofile.address_line2 }}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>{% trans "City" %}</td>
                            <td>{{ customerprofile.employerprofile.city }}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>{% trans "State" %}</td>
                            <td>{{ customerprofile.employerprofile.state }}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>{% trans "Zip code" %}</td>
                            <td>{{ customerprofile.employerprofile.zip_code }}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <table class="table table-bordered">
                        <tr>
                            <th colspan="2"><h2>{% trans "References" %}</h2></th>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>{% trans "Reference 1 - Fullname" %}</td>
                            <td>{{ customerprofile.referencesprofile.ref1_fullname }}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>{% trans "Reference 1 - Phone" %}</td>
                            <td>{{ customerprofile.referencesprofile.ref1_phone }}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>{% trans "Reference 1 - Link" %}</td>
                            <td>{{ customerprofile.referencesprofile.ref1_link }}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>{% trans "Reference 2 - Fullname" %}</td>
                            <td>{{ customerprofile.referencesprofile.ref2_fullname }}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>{% trans "Reference 2 - Phone" %}</td>
                            <td>{{ customerprofile.referencesprofile.ref2_phone }}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>{% trans "Reference 2 - Link" %}</td>
                            <td>{{ customerprofile.referencesprofile.ref2_link }}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
    <script>window.print()</script>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: So, I don't mean any disrespect, but isn't the link to a tutorial that literally explains how to do exactly what you are asking?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jquery or even javascript for this - just good old CSS.

Note that I just dodgied up a table with dummy content - but used the background colors from the site you mentioned.

```css
table{border-collapse: collapse;}
tr, th, td{border:solid 1px #fff}
td{width:50px; padding:15px}
th{background:#006599; color :#fff}

tr:nth-child(even){background:#c7d4e5}
tr:nth-child(odd){background:#E5E5E5}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr><th>Col 1</th><th>Col 2</th></tr>
    <tr><td>1a</td><td>1b</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2a</td><td>2b</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3a</td><td>3b</td></tr>
    <tr><td>4a</td><td>4b</td></tr>
    <tr><td>5a</td><td>5b</td></tr>
    <tr><td>6a</td><td>6b</td></tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: You should try this to my code. It produces some mistakes, because I have tables in table. How could I work that problem.

Comment: nested tables will be the same concept - just determine the selector specificity and go from there. First apply the styling to the parent table  to make sure that that works and tehn apply to the nested table. It is better if you learn to do it yourself - then you know how to do it in the future. I have shown you the approach but you need to take it from there.  We learn best by trying it ourselves.  Happy Coding :)